# Is it possible to use flex box to grow buttons as they wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 buttons in a flex box setting with the last button aligned to the right. I need it to be responsive so that as the buttons wrap, they grow to fit the container width. Is this possible to achieve without using media queries?

Currently I have example of what I want to achieve using media query here, but this relies on pixels which is not ideal:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-txcwwx?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Not possible. You need the media query. (That's why they exist.)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but using media queries with pixels won't work if the user has changed the font size in their browser settings right? So in my example I have the media query set at 282px, but if the user has their font size turned up, won't this media query not correspond correctly to the correct timing of when the last button would wrap?